# How to check if a character of a string contains an integer in Scala?

Tags: scala

For example, "AB3" should return true, whereas "Dfw" should return false.

There are methods which completely checks if the string is int or not, but not part of it? Is there an easier method to do so in scala?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can combine the [`Char#isDigit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Char.html#isDigit:Boolean) predicate with [`StringOps#exists`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#exists(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean) which tests if any character of a `String` validates a predicate:

```
"AB3".exists(_.isDigit) // true
"Dfw".exists(_.isDigit) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"[0-9]".r.findFirstMatchIn("hu1sagd").isDefined
```

Comment: `testString.matches(".*\\d.*")`